# Romania TST 1995 -irreducible Polynomail

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Question is:

Let $f$ be an irreducible (in $Z[x]$) monic polynomial with integer coefficients and of odd degree greater than $1$. Suppose that the modules of the roots of $f$ are greater than $1$ and that $f(0)$ is a square-free number. Prove that the polynomial $g(x) = f(x^3)$ is also irreducible.

Here is my idea to approach:

Suppose contradict, $g(x)$ is reducible then $g(x)$ is a multiple of an irreducbile $h(x)$. It means $f(x^3)$ is a multiple of $h(x)$. Let $\omega=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ then $f(x^3)$ is a multiple of $h(\omega x)$ and $h(\omega^2 x)$. I'm stuck here. I wonder but can't proof the $h(x),h(\omega x) $ and $h(\omega^2x)$ are pairwise coprime polynomials.

Somebody can help me?? Thanks!

Comment: The factor $h(x)$ remains irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$. Implying that either $h(\omega^kx)$, $k=0,1,2$ are all equal up to a scalar multiple (necessarily a power of $\omega$), or pairwise coprime. In the former case $h(x)=r(x^3)$ for some monic polynomial $r(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, leading to $r(x)=f(x)$ and a contradiction. In the latter case I guess that you can arrive at contradiction about the square-free assumption. I further guess that the assumption about the roots is to rule out the possibility $f(0)=1$, but cannot tell for sure.

Comment: The statement I quote in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4315547 is a generalization of this problem, so it might be useful (maybe it's a little too general for math contest)